# I swore accidentally without thinking in something else other than Allah

Tags: sin, oaths, halal-haram

I accidentally didn t think it and swore on something else other than Allah.3 seconds later I got terrified cause I understand I did a major sin.
I swore in form of order for exampe Swearing to something else to do something It is considered as a sin. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You are just writing statements,  what is the question exactly?!

Comment: Is it major sin?